# while calling c++/cli code from c# code methods are not exposed

Tags: c++-cli

We have updated the old managed extensions C++ project to c++/cli project

While updatding compiler forced us to uupdate the syntax as following::

**NEW SYNTAX**

*Declaration in .h file*

```
            ref class CRsiComHandle{}

            ref class CRsiNetwork{

            void SetCom(CRsiComHandle% aComHandle);
            }
```

*Definition in .Cpp File*

```
            CRsiComHandle^ com;

            void CRsiNetwork::SetCom(CRsiComHandle% aComHandle)
            {
                            com = %aComHandle;
            }
```

**OLD SYNTAX**

*Declaration in .h file*

```
            __gc class CRsiComHandle{}

            __gc class CRsiNetwork{

            void SetCom (CRsiComHandle& aComHandle);
               }
```

*Definition in .cpp file*

```
            CRsiComHandle* com;
            void CRsiNetwork::SetCom (CRsiComHandle& aComHandle)
            {
                            com = &aComHandle;
            }
```

**Problem :** 
 In C# code, our dll is not exposing the respective methods which having handlers. 
How to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Implicitly dereferenced object arguments are a native C++ feature and not supported in other languages.  No point in trying to pass the argument by reference at all, the method doesn't create a new instance of the class.  It should be void CRsiNetwork::SetCom(CRsiComHandle^ aComHandle)

Comment: In addition to what Hans said, none of the code you show will be exposed to C# because the `public` keyword is missing from the classes.

Comment: I have public keyword i actual application, I understood what @Hans said but I am eager to know why its not exposing the method to c# ?